# Programmatically create configurable products

Tags: magento-1, import, exception

I am trying to create a product importer in Magento. Probably exception is thrown by the line: `$product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);`. When I comment it, no exceptions are thrown. What is wrong with the array?

```
$configurableProductsData = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [attribute_id] => 135
                    [label] => 00
                    [value_index] => 48
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [attribute_id] => 92
                    [label] => Print
                    [value_index] => 511
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [attribute_id] => 135
                    [label] => 0
                    [value_index] => 48
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [attribute_id] => 92
                    [label] => Print
                    [value_index] => 511
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 0
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [attribute_id] => 135
                    [label] => 2
                    [value_index] => 49
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [attribute_id] => 92
                    [label] => Print
                    [value_index] => 511
                    [is_percent] => 0
                    [pricing_value] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Exception:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`c1_estelles`.`catalog_product_super_link`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE C)' in /var/www/clients/client1/web97/web/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/clients/client1/web97/web/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/clients/client1/web97/web/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/clients/client1/web97/web/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/clients/client1/web97/web/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error's right there for you to see

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

PHP is telling you  it can't perform the SQL you asked it to perform, because a SQL foreign key constraint failed.

If you look at the details of the error, you know this is on the table `catalog_product_super_link`.

```
(`c1_estelles`.`catalog_product_super_link`,
```

and it's the key named `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID`.

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` 
FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` 
(`entity_id`) ON DELETE C)' in
```

You can look at the table definition if you run the following SQL query.

```
mysql> SHOW create table catalog_product_super_link;
CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link` (
  `link_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Link ID',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product ID',
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Parent ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`link_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID_PARENT_ID` (`product_id`,`parent_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PARENT_ID` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_LINK_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PARENT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=367 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Super Link Table'
```

The specific definition for our key is

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_LNK_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` 
FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) 
REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

In plain english, that's saying "Every `product_id` in `catalog_product_super_link` needs to have a corresponding `entity_id` in `catalog_product_entity`".

So, there's nothing specifically wrong with your array of information — the problem seems to be in your program logic.  My guess would be you're inserting those attributes before the actual product is saved to the `catalog_product_entity` table.

Answer (score 2):

I think that array structure that you put inside

```
$product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData) is wrong.
```

It should be like this

```
array(
    'product_id' => 'product_id'
)
```

where `product_id` is id of simple products which you want to add to configurable.

Answer (score 1):

Each entry of `$configurableProductsData` should be added like

```
$configurableProductsData[$productId] = array(                                             
  '0' => array(                                                               
    'attribute_id' => '16',                                                   
    'label' => 'Green',                                                       
    'value_index' => '53',                                                    
    'is_percent' => 0,                                                        
    'pricing_value' => ''                                                     
  )                                                                           
);
```

where `$productId` can be fetched using SKU by the following call:

```
$productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('product-sku');
```

In your case, 0,1 & 2 might not be valid product ids(*entity_id*) in the `catalog_product_entity` table.